# Classic ASP: Execute 2 Update Statements in single function

Tags: asp-classic

I am writing Classic ASP program.In one function, I have to use 2 update statements to one table in one function. First Statement is update the quantity of invoice and second update statement is base on that update Purchase Order quantity and Purchase Requisition quantity, I need to update one flag field. Can I write in same function as following:

```
   SET RS = app.Execute("SELECT PRInvoiceNo, Quantity FROM PurchaseOrderDetails WHERE CoID='" & param & "'")
   do while RS.EOF=false
       app.Execute("UPDATE PurchaseRequisitionDetails SET PO_Quantity = PO_Quantity + " & RS("Quantity") & " WHERE CoID='" & param & "' AND PRInvoiceNo = '" & RS("PRInvoiceNo") & "'")
        app.Execute("UPDATE PurchaseRequisitionDetails SET FullyPaidFlag=CASE WHEN PO_Quantity >= Quantity THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  WHERE CoID='" & param & "' AND PRInvoiceNo = '" & RS("PRInvoiceNo") & "'")
   RS.MoveNext
   loop
```

The problem is in the loop the first statement is properly worked. Second one not work. What can it be? Can I do like this or not?

Comment: This should work correctly.  What's your error?

P.S.  Please, please don't forget to escape your variables!

Comment: thanks for your reply.. escape variables work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have to go, but be sure to check the following:

1. Response.Write(RS.RecordCount) -- are there any records?  Or, do a Response.Write("hello") inside the loop to make sure.
2. Check that RS("Quantity"), param, etc are not null.  If they are, your string concatenation will result in a null string.

Also, please, please don't forget to escape your variables!

`Replace(param, "'", "''")`

Good night!

Comment: thanks a lot! escaping variables work now. thanks you so much for reply.